# Declaração múltiplas de variáveis no Javascript

Tags: javascript, declaração-de-variável

Tem se tornado bastante comum declarar variáveis em múltiplas linhas no JavaScript. Principalmente, quando são inicializadas depois:

```
var var1 = null,
    var2 = null,
    var3 = 0;
```

O "normal" seria assim:

```
var var1 = null;
var var2 = null;
var var3 = 0;
```

- Por que a declaração múltiplas de variáveis em múltiplas linhas tem se tornado tão comum?
- Quais as diferenças entre as duas?
- Quando eu devo usar uma ou outra?

Comment: Não sou muito fã de separar as variáveis com vírgula porque assim a primeira e a última linha ficam diferente das linhas do meio. Isso significa que precisamos editar a linha do `var3` se quisermos adicionar um `var4` na lista. Dito isso, tem gente que acha a primeira versão mais mais bonita.

Comment: Só para mostrar como é mais questão de gosto mesmo, eu a contrário do @hugomg já prefiro usar com vírgulas, assim quando você precisa definir várias variáveis vazias no inicio de uma função, da pra fazer tudo numa linha economizando caracteres.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É sobretudo uma questão de estilo, questão de gosto.
Não há diferença de funcionamento entre uma e outra.

A única vantagem de declarar com virgulas é poupar uns bites por não precisar de usar `var` tantas vezes e assim fazer o script ligeiramente mais pequeno. Para poupar os tais bites deve fazê-lo *inline*, na mesma linha como o [@hugomg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40586/declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-m%C3%BAltiplas-de-vari%C3%A1veis-no-javascript/40590?noredirect=1#comment79885_40590) também apontou).

Comment: O script só fica mais pequeno se as declarações separadas por vírgula estiverem todas na mesma linha - se tiver tudo indentado com espaços como no caso do OP então o número de bytes é o mesmo. Dito isso, qualquer bom minificador de Javascript já faz esse truque (e muito mais) sem precisar que você mude seu estilo no código fonte.

Comment: @hugomg verdade, eu assumí isso mas é melhor deixar na resposta para quem não pense nisso naturalmente. Obrigado.

Comment: Achei que pudesse ter alguma problema quanto a manutenção ou possibilidades de erros.. mas pelo visto são só bytes mesmo.

Pesquisando na internet, encontrei que se vc esquecer de uma vírgula no multilinha, a próxima var vai ser global. Mas usando o `'use strict'`, o erro é acusado..

Answer (score 5):

Existem muitos argumentos a favor de ambos os lados que vão desde inserção automática de ponto-vírgula, *hoisting* e legibilidade até "esse é mais fácil de fazer *diff* do que esse".

No final tudo se resume a **Escolha o que é melhor para você**.

Existe, porém, um critério objetivo que pode fazer você optar pela declaração de um único `var`, que é a performance. De fato, a performance da declaração de um único `var` é superior a da declaração de mútiplos `var` como indica os seguintes testes:

- http://jsperf.com/multiple-var
- http://jsfiddle.net/ufmmN/

Pode ser uma diferença pequena e irrelevante, mas é o único critério que vai além da subjetividade.

Comment: Como o [`hoisting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) entra nessa história?

Comment: Os argumentos não são muito claros. Os argumentos que encontrei são do tipo : "A single var statement makes it easier to avoid hoisting confusions that can occur when declaring vars in blocks." Essa é uma frase dita pelo Douglas Crockford criador do JSON e JSLint no seguinte link: https://plus.google.com/+RonWaldon/posts/8kgP8EU56LS

Comment: tentarei mais tarde listar os argumentos que existem para ambos os lados

Comment: Não sei se esses testes de porformance são tão confiáveis. Você vai gastar muito mais tempo medindo o tempo do que rodando as declarações. Além disso, as duas formas de declarar as variáveis devem gerar momesmo bytecode depois de compiladas.

Comment: O exemplo no jsfiddle mostra uma diferença muito maior por um erro no código, você usou o `singleVarStart` em vez do `multiVarsStart` na linha 41 e por isso ele da um valor muito maior